# Python - Extract data from csvfile1 and write to csvfile2 based on values in columns

Tags: python, csv

I have data stored in a csv file :

```
ID;Event;Date
ABC;In;05/01/2015
XYZ;In;05/01/2016
ERT;In;05/01/2014
...     ...       ...
ABC;Out;05/01/2017
```

First, I am trying to extract all rows where Event is "In" and saves thoses rows in a new csv file. Here is the code i've tried so far:

[UPDATED : 05/18/2017]

```
with open('csv_in', 'r') as f, open('csv_out','w') as f2:
    fieldnames=['ID','Event','Date']
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n', 
    fieldnames=fieldnames)
    wr = csv.DictWriter(f2,dialect='excel',delimiter=';', 
    lineterminator='\n',fieldnames=fieldnames)
    rows = [row for row in reader if row['Event'] == 'In']
    for row in rows:
        wr.writerows(row)
```

I am getting the following error : " ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'I', 'D'

[/UPDATED]

1/ Any thoughts on how to fix this ?

2/ Next step, how would you proceed to do a "lookup" on the ID (if exists several times as per ID "ABC") and extract the given "Date" value where Event is "Out"

output desired :

```
ID        Date         Exit date
ABC     05/01/2015     05/01/2017
XYZ     05/01/2016
ERT     05/01/2014
```

Thanks in advance for your input.

PS : can't use panda .. only standard lib.

Comment: How exactly are "columns" in your `csv_in` delimited?

Comment: They are separated by a " ; "
Example : 

ABC;05/01/2015;05/01/2017

Answer (score 0):

you can interpret the raw csv with the standard library like so:

```
oldcsv=open('csv_in.csv','r').read().split('\n')

newcsv=[]

#this next part checks for events that are in

for line in oldcsv:
    if 'In' in line.split(';'):
       newcsv.append(line)

new_csv_file=open('new_csv.csv','w')
[new_csv_file.write(line+'\n') for line in newcsv]
new_csv_file.close()
```

you would use the same method to do your look-up, it's just that you'd change the keyword in that for loop, and if there's more than one item in the newly generated list you have more than one occurance of your ID, then just modify the condition to include two keywords

Comment: You should use context managers. `with open(filename, 'r') as f: ...`

Answer (score 0):

The error here is because you have not added a delimiter.
Syntax-

`csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')`

For Part 2.

```
import csv
import datetime

with open('csv_in', 'r') as f, open('csv_out','w') as f2:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    wr = csv.writer(f2,dialect='excel',lineterminator='\n')
    result = {}
    for row in reader:
      if row['ID'] not in result:
        # Assign Values if not in dictionary
        if row['Event'] == 'In':
          result[row['ID']] = {'IN' : datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%d/%m/%Y') }
        else:
          result[row['ID']] = {'OUT' : datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%d/%m/%Y') }
      else:
          # Compare dates with those present in csv.
          if row['Event'] == 'In':
            # if 'IN' is not present, use the max value of Datetime to compare
            result[row['ID']]['IN'] = min(result[row['ID']].get('IN', datetime.datetime.max), datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%d/%m/%Y'))
          else:
            # Similarly if 'OUT' is not present, use the min value of datetime to compare
            result[row['ID']]['OUT'] = max(result[row['ID']].get('OUT', datetime.datetime.min), datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%d/%m/%Y'))
    # format the results back to desired representation
    for v1 in result.values():
      for k2,v2 in v1.items():
        v1[k2] = datetime.datetime.strftime(v2, '%d/%m/%Y')
    wr.writerow(['ID', 'Entry', 'Exit'])
    for row in result:
      wr.writerow([row, result[row].get('IN'), result[row].get('OUT')])
```

This code should work just fine. I have tested it on a small input

Comment: Having problems with Part 1 still. When I change code to csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';') the file csv_out generates with only the header items written out like this (with a newline \n between each item) : 
D,a,t,e  
E,v,e,n,t
I,D

Comment: Can you update the csv format in OP. You said in a comment above that its seperated by `;`

Comment: Updated original message. Sorry for that.

Comment: Can you debug and print row after the loop starts `for row in reader:`

Comment: This is what i can see for 1) rows : [{'ID': 'ABC',..., 'Event': 'In'}] 2) reader : <csv.DictReader object at 0x02FB2330> and 3) row : {'ID': 'ABC', ...., 'Event': 'In'}

Comment: I see that you are using your own program here. Also this is when you are using csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';') ?

Comment: Yes, wanted to get part 1 fixed before looking at your part 2 code.

Comment: Ok, so now your problems becomes the output in csv_out. The first issue for ` KeyError: 'Event'`  is now solved. 
 You should change the writer to Dictwriter since you are writing dict.
 - https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter

Comment: I am now using Dictwriter, but it generates a new error (updated OP). It seems to be breaking up every letter of my header.. and therefore does not recognize fieldname items.

Comment: Looks you are not following the documentation closely. `wr.writerows` needs a list of dicts in your case. however you are sending a single dictionary, due to which it is iterating over the keys. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.

Comment: Also , make sure you are calling `writeheader` before `writerows` command